# Applying function to Pandas Data frame and merging resulting data frames into a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yF
import datetime
from functools import reduce


def get_returns_change_period(tic,com,OHLC_COL1,OHLC_COL2):
    df_Stock = yF.download(tickers = tic, period = "38y", interval = "1mo", prepost = False, repair = False)
    df_Stock['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Stock.index)
    df_Stock = df_Stock.sort_values(by='MONTH')
    
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'3M'] = (((df_Stock[OHLC_COL1].shift(2) - df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]))/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]) *100          
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'3M'] = (df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'3M'] * 100 )/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]
    
    
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'2M'] = (((df_Stock[OHLC_COL1].shift(1) - df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]))/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]) *100          
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'2M'] = (df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'2M'] * 100 )/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]
    
    
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'M'] = (((df_Stock[OHLC_COL1].shift(0) - df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]))/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]) *100          
    df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'M'] = (df_Stock[com + ' % Change '+'M'] * 100 )/df_Stock[OHLC_COL2]
    
          
    return df_Stock.filter(regex='MONTH|% Change')
```

Everything works as expected until this point.

```
get_returns_change_period('XOM','EXXON MOBIL','High','Open')
```

Now I am trying to Apply Lambda function to this function.

```
df_Industry = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1', '2'], 'Ticker': ['AIN', 'TILE'], 'Company':['Albany International', 'Interface']})


df1 = df_Industry.apply(lambda x: get_returns_change_period(x.Ticker, x.Company, 'High','Open'), axis=1)

#df1 = df1.T
df1
```

The output has to be data frame which is merged result of multiple stocks which are returned by `get_returns_change_period()` function.

[The problem/solution here is very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250672/4399016). But I am unable to reuse the solution given. Returns for multiple time periods are calculated and returned by the function here:

```
get_returns_change_period()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge the dataframes computed by each return of the `get_returns_change_period` function, you can use the `concat` function of pandas in this way:

```
merged_df = pd.concat(df1.tolist(), axis=1)
```

Here's the output you get on a sample of your data (the last 5 observations):

| Date | MONTH | Albany International % Change 3M | Albany International % Change 2M | Albany International % Change M | MONTH | Interface % Change 3M | Interface % Change 2M | Interface % Change M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 10.1677 | 11.6873 | 14.0497 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 271.476 | 235.975 | 400.949 |
| 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 1.14388 | 3.13983 | 5.61434 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | -92.5231 | 10.4251 | 140.739 |
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | -1.31092 | 0.967072 | 0.92409 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | -90.5255 | 15.9752 | 90.5256 |
| 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 4.85091 | 4.80482 | 1.45181 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | -49.2854 | 15.8085 | 34.4068 |
| 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 15.2679 | 11.3361 | 2.08076 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 77.0512 | 97.8758 | 15.6185 |

Let me know if this meets your requirements!

Comment: It is enough to have only one MONTH column

Comment: Yes, of course, but you can easily keep just one MONTH column. On the other hand, it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, so please explain so that we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: It works. I just removed MONTH from Regex in get_returns_change_period() and added MONTH after lambda apply. It will do.